# Tastypie | Related Resources when the Django ForeignKey uses 'to_field' and not the primary key

Tags: django, tastypie

```
class DeviceResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta :
        queryset = Device.objects.all()
        resource_name='device'


class UpdateResource(ModelResource):
    device = fields.ForeignKey(DeviceResource, attribute='device',full=True, null=True)

    class Meta : 
        queryset = Update.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'update'
        filtering = {'imei' : ALL }
```

Update  Model  has a field 'imei', which maps to 'imei' in the device with ForeignKey

I thought there will be some attribute to_field with which I can write

```
        device = fields.ForeignKey(DeviceResource, to_field='imei'attribute='device',full=True, null=True)
```

but there is no such thing in the tastypie

Here are my Device and Update Models

http://pastebin.com/ENA64RtM

Comment: Did you check the related_field parameter (in the ressources) and [related_name](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#related-name) (in the models)?

Comment: @nnaelle Sorry I didn't get you fully. I did this `device = fields.ForeignKey(DeviceResource, attribute='device',related_name='imei',full=True, null=True)` and `device = fields.ForeignKey(DeviceResource, attribute='device',related_field='imei',full=True, null=True)`,this is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think tastypie supports this well, so if you can change your models to use the implicit primary key I would do so.

That said, the attribute arg refers to the Django model attribute you need to access the related instance, so try `attribute='imei'` if you haven't already.

If you need to reference DeviceResources via IMEI and don't know their .pk see the [tastypie docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-non-pk-data-for-your-urls) for more help with a non-pk lookup.

If you just need filtering for GETs, try this:

```
filtering = {
    device: "ALL_WITH_RELATIONS"
}
```

Then your UpdateResource filter call would be something like

```
/api/v1/update/?device__imei=asdf123...
```